# Python Mayavi - set size of scatter point

Tags: python, mayavi

I've a very simply script with which I'm trying to plot 2 points with a set size:

```
from mayavi.mlab import *

x = [0.,3.]
y = [0.,0.]
z = [0.,0.]
scalars = [1.5,1.5]

pts = points3d(x, y, z,  scalars, scale_factor = 1)
```

However, I can't figure out how, with this simple example, to set the size of the two points so that the points just touch each other. I want to set the size in the same units as the coordinates of the points. So I separate the two points by 3 units and set the size of the two points to 1.5.

However, in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTm3I.png) attached, the two points don't touch like expected.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

In mayavi, the scale of spheres determines their diameter and not their radius.

Use

```
pts = points3d(x, y, z, scalars, scale_factor=2, resolution=100)
```

the `resolution` argument makes a smoother sphere (number of angular points). Beware of high values of resolutions if you intend to display many spheres.